What is the difference between Epic and Drama in Aristotle's Poetics?
Aristotle argues that epic narration may have more complicated plot structures or a "multiplicity of plots," since it implies a higher level of action and character. Both drama and epic are important because of the unities they form between place, time, and action. Homer, for example, employs direct narration without dialogue or combines both which is an example of epic poetry, whereas the uses of dialogue alone is dramatic poetry. On Aristotle's view, epic narration has a more complicated structure since it is not limited at all in time and place. How else would one go about describing this difference? Does epic always entail a master or ultimate narrator, but drama does not allow any grand narratives since all narration occurs only in the dialogue itself and never from any meta-perspective?

Migrate to Literature SE
